# How can I do horizontal swipe until desired element is found in webdriverio for mobile automation?

Tags: android, appium, webdriver-io

I want to do horizontal swipe is there any way it can be done for mobile for android using appium webdriverio.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom swipe method using **io.appium.java_client.TouchAction**

```
public void horizontalSwipeByPercentage(double startPercentage, double endPercentage,
                  double anchorPercentage, AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver) {
  Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
  int anchor = (int) (size.height * anchorPercentage);
  int startPoint = (int) (size.width * startPercentage);
  int endPoint = (int) (size.width * endPercentage);

  new TouchAction(driver)
        .press(PointOption.point(startPoint, anchor))
        .waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(ofSeconds(1)))
        .moveTo(PointOption.point(endPoint, anchor))
        .release().perform();
}
```

> For horizontal swipe, anchor is the fixed y coordinate position